# Delphi / cxGrid сортирует "Ё" раньше других букв

Tags: delphi, строки, сортировка, devexpress

Буква "Ё" идет впереди всех русских букв... Как-то можно поправить такое поведение?

[image: Демонстрация эффекта]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzrRP.png - не вижу повода для возмущения. В DOS (CP866) они шли последними... я что-то вообще не припомню навскидку кодировку, где Ё идёт между Е и Ж...

Comment: Не работал с `DevEx`, но думаю, что где-то в алгоритме сортировки, используемого компонентом, имеется ошибка. Хотя возможно проблема кроется в *выводе* данных, но не в сортировке.

Comment: @Pit, я добавил ответ с еще одним решением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы необходимо включить специальный режим, при котором контрол будет использовать настройки локали при сортировке. Включается этот режим опцией `GridView.DataController.Options.dcoAnsiSort`.

Выдержка из документации компонента:

> If active, a grid control uses Windows locale settings to sort records. This option is useful when grid cells contain native language text.
>   Otherwise, strings are compared based on the 8-bit ordinal value of each character.

Answer (score 5):

Проблема, похоже, внутри компонента. Можно перехватить событие OnCompare и сравнивать самому:

```
procedure Form1.cxGrid1DBTableView1DataControllerCompare( 
                ADataController: TcxCustomDataController;
                ARecordIndex1, ARecordIndex2, AItemIndex: Integer;
                const V1, V2: Variant;
                var Compare: Integer );
var
  s1, s2: string;
  res: Integer;

begin
  s1:=V1;
  s2:=V2;
  res := string.compare(s1,s2);
// string.compare использует текущую локаль, и поэтому сортировка будет правильной
// но можно и указать желаемую локаль - string.compare это позволяет
// может, захотите добавить опций, например, не учитывать регистр или ещё что-то
 Compare:=sign(res);
end;
```